# How to use a different .csl to every chapter in bookdown?

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, pandoc-citeproc

I am writing my dissertation using R Markdown. I have two different citation styles (.csl), one for each chapter. However, I have not found how to use a different citation style for each chapter.

Chapter one citation style is `csl: associacao-brasileira-de-normas-tecnicas.csl`, and Chapter two citation style is `csl: behavioral-ecology-and-sociobiology.csl`

When using Bookdown, only the YAML from the first Rmd file is used. Then, my citations are all formatted according to chapter one citation style. Is there a workaround besides creating individual files for each chapter?

Comment: what's the problem with creating individual files for each chapter?

Comment: Since I have only two documents, this is the solution I am currently using. However, I would like to know if there is  "self-contained" solution for this issue when preparing a larger document.

Comment: not that I'm aware of... you can always write a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/scripting.html), bash or make file, which calls [pandoc-citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc) with different csl files.